# JSON.stringify and angular.toJson not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So I have to objects:

```
var productCopy = {
    "light": true,
    "new": true,
    "available": false
};

var model = {
    "light": true,
    "new": true,
    "available": false
};
```

I need to compare both, so I did this:

```
// Create our 2 strings
var productCopyString = JSON.stringify(productCopy);
var modelString = JSON.stringify(model);
```

and then I did this:

```
return modelString !== productCopyString;
```

but it wasn't working. So I did a console.log like this:

```
console.log('productCopy', productCopyString);
console.log('model', modelString);
console.log('are they different', modelString !== productCopyString)
```

and that returned:

> productCopy {"light":true,"new":true,"available":false}
>
> model {"light":true,"new":true,"available":false}
>
> are they different false

which was strange, so I did this:

```
var productCopyString = angular.toJson(productCopy);
var modelString = angular.toJson(model);
```

And I got the same result.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting. The strings are equal, so `!==` operators gives `false`.

Comment: What isn't working? I ran this in JSBin and the results are as expected. http://jsbin.com/voqagoqawa/edit?js,console

Comment: What's the question, what were you expecting, both strings are the same, applied a not-equality operator on both in comparison, result is false, meaning, both are the same, so *what is strange*?

Comment: `are they different false`  This is a true statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, two strings are equal `===` if they have the same data.

Ex: `'{"light":true,"new":true,"available":false}' === '{"light":true,"new":true,"available":false}'`

Note: In other languages like Java, two strings are equal `==` is they refer to the same instance. In that case, two strings with same data would not be `==`.

Comment: yup, I knew I was doing something stupid, Have been staring at the code so long I couldn't see the wood for the trees